# Adding Child query to related query

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, childrecords

I have a visualforce page showing cases related to an opportunity (I expect 1 to 1).
I query the child case and show it in the Opportunity page more usefully than using related list view.
How would I also add the Case comments to this?
Apex class:

```
public class OpportunityCaseQuery{

    Opportunity Op;

      public OpportunityCaseQuery(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
      OP = (Opportunity) controller.getRecord();        
    }

    public List<Case> getOppCases() {
      return [select id, casenumber, description, session__c, target_Date__c, reason, status, subject, approval_status__c, owner.name, lastModifiedDate,  from case where opportunity__c = :op.id ];
    }

}
```

Visualforce page - you may notice I use two tables b/c I want the description to run full width and expect only 1 result.

```
    <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityCaseQuery" title="Cases" >


       <apex:pageBlock title="Connection">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OppCases}" var="c" id="ConCases">



         <apex:column headerValue="Case"><apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR

    ($Action.case.View,c.id)}" target="_blank">{!c.CaseNumber}

    </apex:outputLink></apex:column>


      <apex:column headerValue="Owner" value="{!c.owner.name}"/>

      <apex:column value="{!c.Status}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!c.Reason}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!c.subject}"/>
      <apex:column headervalue="Last Modified Date"><apex:outputField value="{!c.lastmodifiedDate}"/></apex:column>
      <apex:column value="{!c.Session__c}"/>

      <apex:repeat value="{!cases}" var="case">
    <apex:repeat value="{!case.CaseComments}" var="comment">
        <apex:outputText value="{!comment.CommentBody}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>


    </apex:pageBlockTable>



         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OppCases}" var="c" id="ConCases2" >
         <apex:column value="{!c.description}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>


      </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query for child `CaseComment` records in your extension:

```
oppCases = [SELECT (SELECT CommentBody FROM CaseComments) FROM Case WHERE ...];
```

Then in your markup:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!cases}" var="case">
    <apex:repeat value="{!case.CaseComments}" var="comment">
        <apex:outputText value="{!comment.CommentBody}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: ah, and to show in the vf page?

Comment: @jaw999 See my updates.

Comment: Error: Literal value is required for attribute var in <apex:repeat> in OpportunityCase at line 30 column 5 - i am not sure how to insert the repeat value

Comment: @jaw999 Dumb mistake but a pretty self-descriptive message. Updated my answer.

Comment: hmm, trying as the edit shows gets a Error Error: Unknown property 'OpportunityStandardController.cases'

Comment: @jaw999 You'll have to tweak it to use existing properties. Trying to make you do a little thinking on your own. :P You would use `oppCases` instead as defined by the `getOppCases` method.